# Get historical data in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

I'm trying to get historical data from a server in Team Foundation server 2013, does someone know how? In TFS 2015 there is a way with `AsOf` but it doesn't work in the 2013 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, what I wanted was an endpoint.

I found one, it needs to be formatted to use the data that is there:
`#{server_url}/_api/_wit/workitems?ids=#{workItem_id}`

Answer (score 0):

In TFS2013, you need work with TFS API to get work item historical data. You should use the [WorkItem.Revisions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitem.revisions(v=vs.120).aspx) property.

```cs
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"));
var service = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var wi = service.GetWorkItem(workitemid);
foreach (Revision revision in wi.Revisions)
{
    //historical data
}
```

Have a check on this blog for the details: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx